# Room booking system newbie logic rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently making a website in Rails that will allow the user to create and account and then when logged in he/she will be get a list of all the "rooms" in the database. And then the user will be able to book a one of the rooms. Like a booking system.

So first when the user logges in it will get redirected to the controller booker index. That will get all the rooms from the database and display the information in a table.

The model situation is built up like the User has_many reservations, and the reservation belongs_to User.

So what I want to do is that next to the table (can be on the same row) there should be a click button. And when the user click the button the reservations is created and linked to the user without leaving the current page.
Atm this is what I came up with (in the index.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for(@new_reservation) do |new_res| %>
  <% @all_rooms.each do |r| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= r.room %></td>
        <td><%= r.room_size %></td>
        <td><%= r.building %></td>
        <td><%= r.room_description %></td>
        <td><%= new_res.submit  "Create" %></td>
      </tr>
   <% end %>         
<% end %>
```

and my controller looks like

```
class BookerController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @new_reservation = Reservation.new
    @all_rooms = Room.all
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

and route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
#Log in / Logout functionality 
get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
#The start screen
root 'welcome#index'
#The signup
get '/signup'  => 'users#new' 
get '/book' => 'booker#index'
resources :users
resources :reservations
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do i accomplish so I can on the /book site be able from the list of rooms book one of them. So the a reservations is created and linked to the User. Without leaving the page, I still want the user to be on this page, cause its the main page when logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few things to make this happen:

- If you want your user to stay on the page, you need to make your form
  asynchronous with `remote: true`
- If you want to create the Reservation in your `BookerController#create` method, it needs to be accessible with a HTTP POST
- A simple, straightforward way to do this is to have in your view a form for each potential reservation the user might do

Working example:

app/views/booker/index.html.erb

```
<% @all_rooms.each do |r| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= r.room_size %></td>
  <td><%= r.building %></td>
  <td><%= r.room_description %></td>
  <td>
    <%= form_for(Reservation.new, remote: true, format: :js, url: {controller: "booker", action: "create"}) do |new_res| %>
    <%= new_res.hidden_field :room_id, value: r.id %>
    <%= new_res.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <%= new_res.submit  "Book" %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Here, replace `current_user.id` by whatever gives you the currently logged in user

app/controllers/booker_controller.rb

```
class BookerController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @all_rooms = Room.all
  end

  def create
    new_reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    new_reservation.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private 
  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:room_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/book' => 'booker#index'
  post '/book' => 'booker#create'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

> And when the user click the button the reservations is created and linked to the user without leaving the current page.

You need to learn up on how to make Ajax request in Rails.

http://ericlondon.com/2014/03/13/rails-4-submit-modal-form-via-ajax-and-render-js-response-as-table-row.html

Basically you will need to something like this

```
<%= form_for(@new_reservation, remote: remote) do |new_res| %>
```

Which will send data asynchronosly, you will create the reservation , and render a view for display